# React Native- Scrollable SVG Text

Tags: react-native, svg, scrollview, react-native-svg

My aim is to have scrollable svg text on screen but I can't seem to fathom out how.

Firstly, before I attempted to make the text scrollable, I started of with the following code:

```
<View style={style}>
  <Svg height={height} width={width}>
    <G>
      {this.renderLegend({
        ...config,
        count: 4,
        data: data.datasets,
        paddingTop,
        paddingRight
      })}
    </G>
  </Svg>
</View>
```

And here is my `renderLegend` function:

```
   renderLegend = config => {
      var {
        count,
        data,
        labels = [],
        width,
        height,
        paddingRight,
        paddingTop,
        horizontalOffset = 0
      } = config;
      const fontSize = 12;
      //console.log(data);
      let middle = [...new Array(data.length)].map((_, i) => {
        return (
          <G key={Math.random()}>
            <Text
              key={Math.random()}
              x={
                ((width - paddingRight) / data.length) * i +
                paddingRight +
                horizontalOffset +
                60
              }
              y={paddingTop}
              fontSize={fontSize}
              fill={this.props.chartConfig.color(0.5)}
              textAnchor="middle"
            >
              {data[i].name}
            </Text>

            <Rect
              x={
                ((width - paddingRight) / data.length) * i +
                paddingRight +
                horizontalOffset
              }
              y={paddingTop - 5}
              rx="0"
              ry="0"
              width={4}
              height="4"
              strokeWidth={2}
              stroke={data[i].color ? data[i].color(0.5) : "white"}
              fill="white"
            />
          </G>
        );
      });

      return middle;
    };
```

The above code works fine, it renders SVG text elements side by side across the page. However, in some cases I might have a lot of text elements on there so ideally I want to make it scrollable.

When I try and wrap the `renderLegend` content variable in a `ScrollView`, the text disappears from the screen:

```
return (
  <View key={Math.random()}>
    <ScrollView horizontal={true}>
      <Svg key={Math.random()}>{middle}</Svg>
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
)
```

Is there a reason for it disappearing and is there a way to display to scrollable area with SVG text?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the difference between your first and second code

First

`<Svg height={height} width={width}>`

Second

`<Svg key={Math.random()}>{middle}</Svg>`

Try to specify fixed width and height like in first code

Comment: Still Blank when I try that

Comment: Are you sure view and scroll view are rendering properly. Try setting fixed width and height to them too.

Comment: Do you see your components on Inspector?